# Como obter o retorno de uma function instanciada (new + return) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Eu tenho uma function onde atribuo valores no this, por que ela será instanciada

```
function Teste(){
  this.valor='Valor no this';
  return "Valor no return";
}
```

Instancio ela

```
var t = new Teste();
```

Mas agora, como eu pelo a string `"Valor no return"`?

```
console.log(t.valor);
console.log(t.return);//?
```

Código executando aqui: http://jsbin.com/zariyo/1/edit

Comment: Porque o cara mereceu -1?

Comment: Sei lá, não fui eu.

Comment: Os comentários deveriam explicar o por quê disso, mas enfim...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso não é possível. Você está usando a função como um construtor, então ela retorna o objeto que está sendo criado quando é invocada com `new` (a menos que você retorne outro objeto, mas aí nem faz muito sentido usado `new`).

Já que no seu próprio exemplo você está tentando acessar o suposto retorno como propriedade de `t`, então por que não cria outra propriedade?

```
function Teste(){
  this.valor='Valor no this';
  this.ret = "Valor no return";
}

var t = new Teste();
console.log(t.valor);
console.log(t.ret);
```

Comment: Eu sabia que não dava, pq não consegui fazer. Mas aquela coisa "Por que?" e "Será que não dá mesmo". Obrg

Comment: Porque o construtor precisa retornar o objeto que ele cria. Você até poderia retornar outro objeto (não uma string que é um valor primitivo), mas aí perderia acesso à propriedade `valor` que acabou de criar.

Answer (score 2):

Como o @bfavaretto falou, isso não é possível. O que você pode fazer é criar um método para retornar o valor e encadear com o construtor. Por exemplo:

```
function Teste() {
    this.valor = 'valor no this';

    this.getValor = function() {
        return this.valor;
    }
}

var valor = new Teste().getValor();
```